# Is There Book on Collection of Theorems?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, self-learning, reference-books

For example, there is a book titled  *"Synopsis of Elementary Results in Pure and Applied Mathematics: Containing Propositions, Formulae, And Methods Of Analysis, With Abridged Demonstrations" (Cambridge Library Collection - Mathematics) by George Shoobridge Carr*, which I am told consists of theorem without proof, mostly.

Is there similar type of book on number theory, abstract algebra which mainly consists of theorems/results?

Comment: Not what you seek, but you may be interested in this list: [The Hundred Greatest Theorems](https://web.archive.org/web/20080105074243/http://personal.stevens.edu/~nkahl/Top100Theorems.html); also [here](http://pirate.shu.edu/~kahlnath/Top100.html).